# cordova project on iphone 6s working but not on other iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

My Cordova project works with iPhone 6s. I build it in Xcode and start the emulator, works great with iPhone 6s and iOS 9.3 but if I switch to antoher iPhone device like iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus it starts the app but doesn't show anything. I can tell that it starts because I inserted several alerts in the services that are called during the start process.

Am I overseeing something or is there something to add?

P.S.: not working with iOS 10 at all but that's another problem.

Comment: Which plugins you have used?

Comment: Plugins: Device, Whitelist and statusbar. Want to implement the Apple-Watch-Plugin later to connect it with the apple watch. But first this should work ... and I do not have an apple developer license yet.